# Finding min and max in a list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have a list of tuples, say:

```
    [(a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(b,1),(b,2),(b,3)]
```

where a and b are integers and 1,2,3 are floats,
how do I create a new dictionary for the corresponding min and max for each of the elements i.e a and b?
Like for minimum it would be {a:1, b:1} and for maximum it would be {a:3,b:3}.

Comment: what did you try till now?

Comment: But `a` & `b` are variable names and `1`, `2`, & `3` are integers...

Comment: I think it should look like this https://gist.github.com/nuncjo/766f19886b029091d29e

Comment: `d = {}` (new line & indent) `for k, v in list_of_tuples:` (new line & indent) `d[k] = d.get(k,[])+[v]` . This returns a `dict` object keyed by your variables `a` and `b`, etc., and the values will be *list* of each value in the pair, so you can then do `min(d[a])` to get the min, and `max(d[a])` to get the max.

Answer (score 2):

Very brute-force solution,should be easy to understand.

```
minDict={}
maxDict={}
for a,b in lst:
    if a not in minDict:
        minDict[a]=b
    elif b<minDict[a]:
        minDict[a]=b
    if a not in maxDict:
        maxDict[a]=b
    elif b>minDict[a]:
        maxDict[a]=b

print minDict
print maxDict
```

Output:

```
{a: 1, b: 1}
{a: 3, b: 3}
```

Here's another option that uses tuple unpacking and dictionary generator statements wrapped in a function, to return your dict of min and dict of max.

```
def getMinMax(lst):
    # Function returns dict of min, dict of max
    #   from a list of tuples each of len==2
    d = {}
    for k, v in lst:
        d[k] = d.get(k,[])+[v]
    return {k: min(d[k]) for k in d}, {k: max(d[k]) for k in d}
```

Use it like this:

```
lst = [(a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(b,1),(b,2),(b,3)]
minD, maxD = getMinMax(lst)
```

Output:

```
{a: 1, b: 1}
{a: 3, b: 3}
```

Comment: "where a and b are integers"